# Get the list of certain columns wihout duplicates from a model object

Tags: python, django

I have a model object such as

```
class MyMenu(models.Model):
  key= m.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
  name = m.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now there is data like this,

```
  key,name
  a  hiro
  b  hiro
  c  fusa
  d  yoshi
  e  yoshio
  f  fusa
```

Now I would like to get the `name` column without duplication.

As a result I would like to get `["hiro","fusa","yoshi","yoshio"]`

It is possible to do this with for loop, however this way is awkward and slow.

Is there any good method to use a model object?

Comment: `models.MyMenu.objects.values('name').distinct()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
MyMenu.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

This will perform the uniqness filter at the database side, so normally this will definitely outperform a variant where the uniqness is done at the Django/Python-layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a non-duplicated list of names from MyMenu by using a simple QuerySet. Try this:

```
MyMenu.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```